# Two actions at once in a flask function: redirect user and update database

Tags: python, html, database, flask

I am unable to create a Flask function that first redirect an user to an url and second update values in a database. I am able to create a function that updates values first, but this creates unecessary delay for the user which I am trying to avoid.

I'm trying to build a website which links to relevant web pages for a specific research subjet. It has a MySql database which contains 5 columns: Id, Url, Title, Points. So, let's suppose the research subject is hockey, then it could have a data row as (55, https://www.nhl.com/flames, Official Calgary Flames Website, 0).

My goal with the points column is to track which urls are the more popular. Best case scenario: when someone clicks on a link, it opens the link in a new tab first then updates the "point" column in the database for the specified text. I'm able to make it work the other way around, where it updates the database first then redirect the user, but this causes a delay I'm trying to avoid.

My code is structured as follow:

I have a function in Python that displays all the urls in a page.

```
@main.route('/display', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def display():
  results = execute_statement(f"SELECT * FROM database", "all")
  return render_template("display.html", results=results)
```

Then I have an html template that displays each item of the database. It displays the title (item[2]), the points (item[3]), the url (item[1]) and the title (item[2]). With above example, it would display title as Official Calgary Flames Website, points as 0 and href as https://www.nhl.com/flames. It also opens the href in a new tab.

```
{% for item in results %}
          <h2>
            {{ item[2] }} 
          </h2>
          <p> score: {{ item[3] }}) </p>
          <p> {{ item[1] }} </p>
          <a onclick="{{ url_for('admin.read', id=item[0])}}" href="{{ item[1] }}" target="_blank" class="item-link">Go to webpage<i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></a>
{% endfor %}
```

Finally, I have a Python function that is supposed to add points in the page and return original tab to last visited url.

```
@admin.route('/read/<id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def read(id):
   execute_statement(f"UPDATE indexed SET Points = Points + 1 WHERE Id = {id}", "update")
   return redirect(redirect_url())
```

Right now, with the code as above, it opens the page without any delay, but doesn't add points in the database. I have tried different approach to open the url first then update the database but none of them worked:

- I tried adding a url parameter in admin read (i.e. @admin.route('/read//')), but the return redirect statement needs to be after the update statement, so there is a noticeable delay. Also you can't pass the url this way because Flask will interpret the / from the url as new parameters and will return an error).
- I tried adding both the "admin.read" and the url as href elements, but it opens both at once and not separatly. For example it tries to open "/read/55/https://www.nhl.com/flames" instead of opening "read/55/" then "https://www.nhl.com/flames" separatly.
- I tried adding both the "admin.read" and the url as onclick elements, but it doesn't update nor open the url.